# SSH Server Side, Specify Algorithm Per Host

Tags: sshd

On a server running SSH I need it to accept some legacy algorithms for 1 particular host for SSH so that I can copy files from the client to the server. I can't change the client side because its old and trash. So on the server side I have edited the /etc/sshd_config with the below and it fixes my issue.

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

However, the problem is, ssh-rsa is insecure. So I don't wanna just leave it like that. How can I set it so that if a source IP is 1.2.3.4 I can specifically allow those algorithms to work for that host, and that host alone can use those algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

The same as you specify any other per-host configuration

```
Host my.hostname.example.com
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

btw you shouldn't need the `HostKeyAlgorithms` option if you just want to connect to an old remote host.

Comment: I've already tried that, and it doesn't work when I put "host 1.2.3.4".   After you apply it:

    $ sudo systemctl restart sshd
    Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xeu ssh.service" for details.

Comment: @johnsmith, I see you are talking about server side. This should be in the global `sshd_config`. See https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html And what is the error in logs? No `Host` directive? Probably what you want is not possible and perhaps your best bet would be to run a separate SSHD server process on a different port with special configuration to allow only certain users and other hardening. Also firewall it to allow connections from the desired host only.

Comment: Is `Host …` recognized in `sshd_config`? `Match host …` is. (`Host …` and `Match host …` are recognized in `ssh_config`.)

Comment: @SottoVoce, didn't spot this in man, I guess it makes sense to write your own answer as this seems to be the correct solution. I would add to mine but credit better goes to you.

Answer (score 0):

The way to have `sshd` use different configuration options for a host (or for a user) is to use a `Match` conditional block of lines.  In this case `Match Host ...` or `Match Address ...` would be the most appropriate, depending on whether `sshd` can resolve the connecting client's hostname or IP address.  As an example:

```
Match Address 10.11.12.13 10.9.8.7
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

The `sshd_config` man page has good details for using `Match`, but one thing that most man pages don't make very clear is the correct position in the sshd_config file for Match blocks:  **At the end of the file.**

The man page on my Ubuntu 20.04 says:

> If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file, until either another Match line or the end of the file.

You have to interpret that sentence carefully to see that the lines following Match are not expected to be global config directives, just ones in other Match blocks until the end of the file.

A comment block in the source code reveals this more explicitly, as seen in [this answer last year](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711672/531636).  When a Match block is found, the `activep` variable is cleared (set to 0), and no parameters in the rest of the file are treated as global config directives - they're all part of Match blocks.

Most of that answer was about a couple of quirks that aren't relevant to this question. I linked to it because it shows the comment in the source code.